# Every CW complex is homotopically equivalent to a simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

I saw a claim in an old version of the book of Fuchs and Fomenko saying that every CW complex is homotopically equivalent to a simplicial complex.

I would like to see a proof of this claim. Hopefully not the one on Hatcher's book (Th 2C.5, page 182) nor on Gray's book.

Essentially the way I thought about proving this statement is by showing that the statement is trivial on the null and one dimensional skeletons, and then say that the closure of every cell of dimension at least 2 admits a triangulation, and every $n$-dimensional triangle is homeomorphic to the $n$-simplex, making the two underlying topological spaces homeomorphic and therefore homotopy equivalent.

My issue is that this argument seems too short compared to (Hatcher, Th 2C.5, page 182), and proves something that is stronger than the actual claim, that is, I prove that every CW complex is homeomorphic to a simplicial one. Whereas this does sound plausible for a pleb like me, I think this would potentially make a lot of theory redundant, for example we wouldn't need both a simplicial and a cellular approximation theorem, which makes me think that I am definitely missing something important.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does your proof work out with $S^n$ viewed as a CW complex with just two cells: one $n$-cell attached to a single $0$-cell by the constant function on its boundary? (In this case, there is a homeomorphism, but I don't think your proof will give that.)

Comment: Basically in order to triangulate the boundary of the $D^n$ which borders the $n$-sphere, I would need to have $n+1$ points on the boundary of the $D^n$, so I may arbitrarily add $0$-cells to the boundary of the $D^n$ which are in general position and then obtain a triangulatable boundary.

Comment: To my recollection, there are CW complexes with one cell each in dimensions 0, 1, and 2 and no other cells which are not homeomorphic to any simplicial complex. Try something where the gluing map $\partial D^2\to S^1$ undergoes a $x*\sin(1/x)$-like infinite oscillation?

Comment: That won't work. You need to do some work in the interior of the $D^n$. I think @Curious's suggestion will convince you that not only does your line of proof not work, but that what you are trying to prove is false: there are CW complexes that are not homeomorphic to simplicial complexes.

Comment: It seems to me you haven’t given adequate consideration to the attaching maps. Your triangulations may fail to make the attaching maps into simplicial maps.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, and especially for your example, @Curious. Indeed I can now see that my idea already fails at dimension 2.

I am still curious for a reference of a concise proof if anyone has one.